# Substituting elements of a list with elements of another list

Tags: python, list

Suppose we have the following lists:

```
t0=[('soybean','apple','banana', 'vegetable_oil'), ('soybean','bay','milk', 'smoke','orange'), ('cream','gelatin', 'watermelon')]
t1=[('soybean', 'vegetable_oil'), ('bay', 'smoke'), ('gelatin', 'watermelon')]
t2=['soybean:vegetable_oil', 'bay:smoke', 'gelatin:watermelon']
```

For each element in `t1` I want to go through `t0` and replace the strings with the ones in `t2` so that I get:

```
[[('apple','banana', 'soybean:vegetable_oil'), ('soybean','bay','milk', 'smoke','orange'), ('cream','gelatin', 'watermelon')],
[('soybean','apple','banana', 'vegetable_oil'), ('soybean','bay:smoke','milk','orange'), ('cream','gelatin', 'watermelon')],
[('soybean','apple','banana', 'vegetable_oil'), ('soybean','bay','milk', 'smoke','orange'), ('cream','gelatin:watermelone')]]
```

Mathematica has a function for doing such operation called `OrderlessPatternSequence` I wonder how one can make this in Python?

**UPDATE:** A simpler example:

Suppose:

```
l0=[('a','b','c'),('d','e','f','g'),('b','d')]
```

we also have

```
l1=[('a','c'),('e','g')]
```

and

```
l2=['a:c','e:g']
```

`l0` has two elements, I want to go through each element and if `('a','c')` or `('e','g')` from `l1` appear in it together, I replace them with `'a:c'` and `'e:g'` on each iteration. So I have to go TWO times over `l0` once to check if I have `('a','c')` anywhere and once to see if I have `('e','g')`
so the output would be

```
[[('a:c','b'),('d','e','f','g'),('b','d')],
 [('a','b','c'),('d','e:g','f'),('b','d')]]
```

Comment: show your functional code

Comment: I mentioned that is in Mathematica, I do it there as `Table[t0//. {OrderlessPatternSequence[t1[[i, 1]], t1[[i, 2]], 
      p___]} :> {t2[[i]], p}, {i, Length[t2]}];`

Comment: you should add specific tags to your question as well as your code

Comment: Maybe mentioning Mathematica does not help in this case - as it is a different software, I am trying to implement this on Python thus I added the tags Python and List. Do you suggest better tags?

Comment: Hello @William, could you explain what the algorithm needs to do in a bit more detail? It's not clear to me what "For each element in t1 I want to go through t0 and replace the strings with the ones in t2" means, and it's hard to deduce by just looking at the input/output.

Comment: Sure @CihanCeyhan. Suppose we have a simpler example `l0=[('a','b','c'),('d','e','f','g'),('b','d')]` we also have `l1=[('a','c'),('e','g')]`, and `l2=['a:c','e:g']`,`l0` has two elements, I want to go through each element and if `('a','c')` or `('e','g')` from `l1` appear in it together, I replace them with `'a:c'` and `'e:g'`. so the output would be `[[('a:c','b'),('d','e','f','g'),('b','d')],[('a','b','c'),('d','e:g','f'),('b','d')]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
t0=[('soybean','apple','banana', 'vegetable_oil'), ('soybean','bay','milk', 'smoke','orange'), ('cream','gelatin', 'watermelon')]
t1=[('soybean', 'vegetable_oil'), ('bay', 'smoke'), ('gelatin', 'watermelon')]
t2=['soybean:vegetable_oil', 'bay:smoke', 'gelatin:watermelon']

result = []
for v1, v2 in zip(t1, t2):
    out = []
    for i in t0:
        common = set(v1).intersection(i)
        if set(v1) == common:
            out.append(tuple(list(set(i) - common) + [v2]))
        else:
            out.append(tuple(i))
    result.append(out)

from pprint import pprint
pprint(result, width=200)
```

Prints:

```
[[('apple', 'banana', 'soybean:vegetable_oil'), ('soybean', 'bay', 'milk', 'smoke', 'orange'), ('cream', 'gelatin', 'watermelon')],
 [('soybean', 'apple', 'banana', 'vegetable_oil'), ('soybean', 'milk', 'orange', 'bay:smoke'), ('cream', 'gelatin', 'watermelon')],
 [('soybean', 'apple', 'banana', 'vegetable_oil'), ('soybean', 'bay', 'milk', 'smoke', 'orange'), ('cream', 'gelatin:watermelon')]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a built-in for doing this in python. That said, here's some code that should do what you want:

```
# assume that t1 and t2 are the same length
for i in range(len(t0)):
    for e1, e2 in zip(t1, t2):
        set0 = set(t0[i])                       # make sets out of t0 and t1 elements
        set1 = set(e1)
        diff = set0 - set1                      # remove elements from t0 that were in t1
        if len(diff) == len(set0) - len(set1):  # check if any elements were removed
            t0[i] = tuple(diff) + (e2,)         # replace element from t0 with the diff plus the replacement
```

It's a nested loop - for each element of `t0`, check every element of `t1`. In each iteration, first make sets out of those elements (`set0` and `set1`), and subtract the set `set1` from the set `set0`. This gives us the elements that are in `set0` but not in `set1`.

Next, we check that the difference in size of `set0` from before and after the set difference is exactly the same as the number of elements in `set1` - this means that we have found and removed *all* elements from `set1` from `set0`. If this is the case, then we replace `t0[i]` with the set we made from it (minus the elements we removed), plus the element from `t2` that we're supposed to replace.

I might be misunderstanding your goal here - if you just want to compare everything with the same index, you can get rid of the nested loop, but I was assuming you wanted to check every possible replacement on every element of `t0`.

Comment: Yes indeed this is for every possible replacement on every element of `t0`

Comment: I am trying to run your code and I get `[('apple', 'banana', 'soybean:vegetable_oil'),
 ('orange', 'milk', 'soybean', 'bay:smoke'),
 ('cream', 'gelatin:watermelon')]` but if you look at my out put for every pair I do the replacement...